# REST Api documentation for Apache CXF application

Tags: rest, cxf, documentation, swagger-ui

We use Apache CXF in our application with jax-rs to build REST Api. As of now, there is no documentation about the various endpoints available and is deployed on Tomcat 8.5 server.

I have done some R&D on how to find a solution. I understand that Swagger can be used.
But, I did not find enough documentation to user swagger with Apache CXF.

I understand that these type of questions are prohibited in the site. At the same time, I am not sure which chat room to use for this purpose.

Any information on this would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the CXF version that you are using, I would suggest to use OpenApiFeature (OpenAPI is newer than Swagger) as described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/openapifeature.html

You can also find multiple sample projects with Swagger or OpenAPI here: https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jax_rs